# Pandas Rows MODE, AVERAGE Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statistics

I have a pandas dataframe with a list of products in rows, and the columns are the sales of current month, current month - 1, current month -2 and current month - 3

[image: Original DF]

for all rows I want to add a new column with MODE(most frequent number in row), average, and number off months with sales more than zero and get something like this

[image: Final result]

So, how can I calculate the MODE for each row and;

- Example first row, 2 and zero are the most frequent, I only can have one value, which one? and how to calculate
- Second row, all number are different, it doesn't have a mode?

How to add the average column off each row?

And last column, get for each row the number off values bigger the zero, I want to count the number of month with sales

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution on a toy `pandas.DataFrame`, albeit there might be some codes that are more efficient.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'MES-1':[1,2,3,4],'MES-2':[2,2,3,-2],'MES-3':[-1,2,-3,-1]})

modes, sup0, avg = [],[],[]
for line in range(df.shape[0]):
    series = pd.Series(df.iloc[line])
    if len(series.mode()) == 1: # If there is indeed a mode
        modes.append(float(series.mode()))
    else:
        modes.append(np.nan)
    i = 0
    for element in series:
        if element > 0:
            i+= 1
    sup0.append(i)
    avg.append(series.mean())

df['Mode'],df['sup0'],df['avg'] = modes, sup0, avg
```

EDIT: Added the code for the average.

As for your question, I think that you should keep the Mode "unknown" for series that don't have any explicit value for it. This is the purpose of `numpy.nan`.

Comment: Thanks, i will test, for the MODE, maybe I will replace the Man values for the average, because I have made an algorithm the calculation the minimal stock and maximum stocks for each product. I have read i should use time series to forecast the sales, but I don't have the knowledge yeat